# Is there a way to call just a certain part of a website into an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, web

I want to use an iframe to target a specific part of a webpage, and only show that part of the webpage (not the whole page). The issue is, I can only use HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. Are there anyways I might be able to do this?

What I'm specifically trying to do is get this shoutbox:
http://tech-revolution.com/forum/vbshout.php?do=detach&instanceid=1
To display in an iframe on another page, but I only want the shoutbox, not the rest of the page.

Comment: why not create the html that includes only the part you want

Comment: Is the webpage in question one that you control?

Comment: @nnnnn It kind of is, its from a forum I'm a "super moderator" on, so I have some influence over it, but I'm not in control of it. I'm working on building a special tool for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont mind calling the whole page you can manipulate a DIV to make it LOOK like this is happening.  The following code worked for me:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; width:608px; height:270px;">
  <iframe  scrolling="no" frameBorder="0"
  src="http://tech-revolution.com/forum/vbshout.php?do=detach&instanceid=1#dbtech_shoutbox1" 
  style="width:728px; height:270px; border:none; margin-left:-60px;"/>  
</div>
```

But perhaps you should check with that component's authors to see if there's a way to render it the way you want on their server and you'll just need to frame a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe webpage is on the same domain, you can use javascript to edit its contents via the standard DOM ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLIFrameElement ). If the iframe webpage is not, the best you can to is have it start scrolling at a specific anchor by adding #anchor to the end of the iframe url.

Comment: If its for a chrome plugin, then you should really mention that in your question, as it sorta changes everything. Also, tag it as such.